# How to convert context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges([". "], true) to a range

Tags: range, add-in, cpu-word

For some reason, I want to get the sentences of my selected text into a range instead of a range collection.

For example, the sample text is: **This is hello world. Welcome everyone. Enjoy the time.**

In the text, I selected **ld. Wel**.

What I want is a range of "This is hello world. Welcome everyone." However, **context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges([". "], true)** returns a range collection.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The key is at the expandTo function.

let rangeCollection = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges([". "], true);
let range = rangeCollection.items[0].expandTo(rangeCollection.items[rangeCollection.items.length-1]);